# MySQL query select variable where not work

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the following query, I get the result of the starting column grouped and the date-based total.

but when I add where to the query, it doesn't return a value. Could you please help?

```
SELECT
  CAST(durus_tablo.Başlangıç AS date) AS expr1,
  CAST(SUM(durus_tablo.`Toplam Süre`) AS time) AS expr2
FROM durus_tablo
GROUP BY durus_tablo.tarih
```

[image: works]

```
SELECT
  CAST(durus_tablo.Başlangıç AS date) AS expr1,
  CAST(SUM(durus_tablo.`Toplam Süre`) AS time) AS expr2
FROM durus_tablo
WHERE CAST(durus_tablo.Başlangıç AS date) BETWEEN 2021 - 10 - 15 AND 2021 - 10 - 17
GROUP BY durus_tablo.tarih
```

[image: added where not work]

my table
[image]

Comment: I would like to check if the problem is the GROUP BY instead of WHERE clause. Try to remove GROUP BY instead to see if you still get the same result.

Comment: Your problem is probably the date format you are using as filter.

Comment: You need to quote the date. Without quotes, you're doing numeric subtraction. `2021 - 10 - 15 = 1996`

Comment: Example of @Barmar's point : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=126be6a2db625c76bf777800cbb0888e

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes after between for dates as without quotes it becomes subtraction result

```
     Where.... '2021-10-15' AND '2021-10-17' 
    GROUP BY durus_tablo.tarih
```